# Open react native app from a link or custom url

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I'm trying to setup deeplinking so that I can link users to the app from an email address. I've gone through the documentation for setting up with expo and I've included the schema for the app name in the `app.json` file

```
 "scheme": "testapp",
```

and on my `NavigationContainer` I've added the prefixes in the linking option ie:

```
<NavigationContainer linking={{
   prefixes: ["testapp://testapp"],
}}>
```

However when I try to open a link, or in the browser using either `testapp://` or `exp://` as per the documentation it just takes me to a google search results page for that query. I've tried in both Android Studio and in Expo Go on my iOS.

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try when use your browser click on second link not for search like this. and then press on continue

[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c54hp.png)

[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUogc.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).